# System of equations for Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors

Tags: matlab

An Eigenvalue and Eigenvector can be derived from the Tensor T by the below equation.

I am trying to get a system of equations for Eigenvalues, Eigenvectors and the Tensor T to derive T.

`T` matrix equation is:

```
(T(i,k)-L(r)*I) * A(r,k) = 0
```

The first entries should be:

```
[(T11-L1)*A11 T12*A12       T13*A13        T14*A14     ]
[T21*A11      (T22-L1)*A12  T23*A13        T24*A14     ]   
[T31*A11      T32*A12       (T33-L1)*A13   T34*A14     ]
[T41*A11      T42*A12       T43*A13        (T44-L1)*A14]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What's wrong with [`eig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html)?

Comment: What is an eigenvalue in your equaton (T(i,k)-L(r)*I)*A(r,k)=0?

Comment: I want to input the eigenvalue and eigenvectors then solve for the tensor,T.  L(r) is the eigenvalues and A(r,k) is the eigenvector and I is the Identiity matrix ([1 0 0 0,0 1 0 0 ;0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1])

Answer (score 2):

First, let's declare the *symbolics* easier using [`sym`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html):

```
T = sym('T%d%d', [4 4]);
A = sym('A%d%d', [4 4]);
L = sym('L', [4 1]);
```

There are several problems with the original code; **1.** `f` is being replaced in each inner iteration. **2.** The inner result should be scalar and thus `I` must not appear there. (Note that you can also define `I` like [`eye(4)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html) instead of writing it manually.)

Here is the corrected version:

```
f = cell(4,1); % Initialize equation system

for r = 1:k
    for k = 1:4
        for i = 1:4
            f{r}(i,k) = T(i,k) * A(r,k);
        end
    end
    f{r} = f{r} - L(r)*diag(A(r,:));
end
```

`f{i}` would be the `ith` slice.

**Note**: As @Schorsch pointed out (and Matlab also shows a *warning*) always try to use another variable name other than `i` (or `j`), since they represent the [*imaginary unit*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html).

Just for fun you can use [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to remove the two inner loops:

```
for r = 1:4
    f{r} = T .* repmat(A(r,:), [4 1]) - L(r)*diag(A(r,:));
end
```

Comment: +1 for the explanations and for introducing `repmat` to eliminate some of the loops. One additional remark, `i` (and `j` for that matter) should not be used as iterators because the are also the [imaginary unit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html) in Matlab.

Comment: Well that's true I will add a comment there, but I was just trying to keep the original code as far as possible.

Comment: I understand that and agree with it. It was just something I wanted to mention for completeness' sake.