# Symbolic Variable as a Variable

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math

I have a syms Array in MatLab:

```
syms A11 A12 A13 A21 A22 A23 A31 A32 A33 a b c x y z

A=[A11 A12 A13;A21 A22 A23;A31 A32 A33]
```

.

How do I replace a symbolic variable A11 with an equation:

```
A11=a*x+b*y+c*z
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
A = sym('[A11 A12 A13;A21 A22 A23;A31 A32 A33]');

A = subs(A,'A11','a*x+b*y+c*z');
```

or

```
A = subs(A,{'A11','A12'},{'a*x+b*y+c*z','100'});
```

Comment: ??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. Error in ==> EigenValuesVectors4x4ToTensorFactor at 10 f=sym(zeros(4,4,4))

Comment: Better yet, create the `A` matrix this way: `A = sym('A%d%d',[3 3]);`.

Comment: @artis_meditari: there is no `f` in the code you posted above or the answer code, the error is from somewhere else. By the way did [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17369389/1698972) answered your question yesterday?